Is publishing to Lightning Message Channels unsupported in Background Utility Bar Items?
I'm trying to get a Background Utility Item (using Aura) to listen for and propagate some events from the Workspace API. It took a little figuring out, but I set up my channel and got the publisher and subscriber written. However, the subscriber is not receiving any events! When I looked in my browser console, I saw some errors with the following message:

Action failed: lightning:messageChannel$controller$publish [Lightning Message Service - Your component must be rendered before you can publish to channel: MyChannel__c

But as a Background Utility Item, the component will never render. Seems like I've hit a really unfortunate limitation here, but I would love to be proven wrong.
Writing a duplicate of the component which implements="utilityItem" instead of implements="backgroundUtilityItem" works smoothly if I open it before switching tabs. That approach is not desirable, however.
